# Jersey client - Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-client

I'm new to JAX-RS and trying to figure out what is happening here:
I have a simple Hello World Jersey REST service running on Glassfish (Eclipse plugin). I can access it successfully from a browser.

Now, I'd like to call it from a Java class (so I can build JUnit tests around it) but I get this error on buildGet() method:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

Unless some magic I'm not aware of happens, I'm not packaging my service and/or client in any jar so it's not related to my application jar signature.

- Anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong?
- Why is the exception triggered on buildGet() metod and not on any method called before?

My main:

```
package com.test;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


public class HelloTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = null;

        try {
            WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:9595/Hello/api/ping");
            Invocation helloInvocation = webTarget.request().buildGet();

            response = helloInvocation.invoke();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My service:

```
package com.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("ping")
public class Hello 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello()
    {
        return "<html>" + "<title>" + "Hello" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello!!!" + "</body></h1>" + "</html>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling on this for a while, it seems that my Maven configuration had issues and some dependencies were not downloaded/built correctly. I restarted a new project, copied my source files and everything started to work as expected.